# How will I add multiple textures without glaux?

Tags: c++, opengl

there's a problem which I don't know how to solve.
I know how to get multiple textures in my 3D openGL and MVC++ 2010 game but the way is extremely slow. The more textures I load the more the game gets slower. It has been 2 weeks since I got stuck with this. I searched many sites but none of them helped me.

I don't want glaux because it keeps giving me errors and is said to have memory leaks.
This is the way I load .RAW textures:

`GLuint texture; //ID to bind with`

```
    GLuint LoadTexture(const char *filename, int imW, int imH){
    unsigned char*data;
    FILE*file;

    file=fopen(filename,"rb");
    if(file==NULL)return 0;
    data=(unsigned char*)malloc(imW*imH*3);
    fread(data,imW*imH*3,1,file);
    fclose(file);

    glGenTextures(1,&texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0x8191,1); //0x8191 means GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,imW,imH,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);
    free(data);
    return texture;
    }
```

I have opengl 2 but I use "glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0x8191,1);" to build mipmaps because "gluBuild2DMipmaps" is slower than that.

```
void model_room(float x, float y, float x2, float y2, float z, float z2){
LoadTexture("tex_floor.raw",512,512);
model_floor(x,y,x2,y2,z,7,7);
glDeleteTextures(1,&texture);

LoadTexture("tex_ceiling.raw",512,512);
model_floor(x,y,x2,y2,z2,4,4);
glDeleteTextures(1,&texture);

LoadTexture("tex_wall.raw",512,512);
model_wall(x,y,x,y2,z,z2,1,1);
glDeleteTextures(1,&texture);

LoadTexture("tex_tiles.raw",512,512);
model_wall(x,y2,x2,y2,z,z2,1,1);
glDeleteTextures(1,&texture);

LoadTexture("tex_diamondtiles.raw",512,512);
model_wall(x2,y2,x2,y,z,z2,1,1);
glDeleteTextures(1,&texture);

LoadTexture("tex_castlepoint.raw",512,512);
model_wall(x2,y,x,y,z,z2,5,3);
glDeleteTextures(1,&texture);
}
```

Over here the code loads the textures and then deletes them every frame. It might not be a good idea but for now it's okay. For "model_wall" and "model_floor", this is the code:

```
    void model_floor(float x, float y, float x2, float y2, float z, float tc1, float tc2){
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0,     0);     glVertex3f(x,  y,  z);
    glTexCoord2f(tc1,   0);     glVertex3f(x,  y2, z);
    glTexCoord2f(tc1,   tc2);   glVertex3f(x2, y2, z);
    glTexCoord2f(0,     tc2);   glVertex3f(x2, y,  z);
glEnd();
    }

    void model_wall(float x, float y, float x2, float y2, float z1, float z2, float tch, float tcv){
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0,     0);     glVertex3f(x,   y,  z2);
    glTexCoord2f(tch,   0);     glVertex3f(x2,  y2, z2);
    glTexCoord2f(tch,   tcv);   glVertex3f(x2,  y2, z1);
    glTexCoord2f(0,     tcv);   glVertex3f(x,   y,  z1);
glEnd();
    }
```

I just want a good way to load textures without slowing down the game and it's not important to only load raw files but anything that is recommended. I'm not a Win Base programmer so I may want some explanation on those type of codes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you're new here, be sure to inform yourself about the accept and up-vote features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might not be a good idea to load and destroy all textures every frame? **Definitely** not a good idea and surely the cause of your performance drop! That's what texture objects are for (the IDs you get from `glGenTextures`). These are handles to the textures in video memory. So you load all your textures at start, then just bind the neccessary texture (using `glBindTexture`) before drawing (before the `model_wall` calls). And then at the end of your program you destroy them using `glDeleteTextures`.

By your mentioning of glaux, I assume you are using quite old learning ressources, maybe you should look for a better tutorial/book if you got this practice from there.

Answer (score 2):

Loading the textures every frame is a terrible idea, and it's probably why your game slows down. Just load them once and then make them active when using them.

Comment: So you mean I should generate them once with there IDs and then use the IDs?